# Shell script logic for SVN exporting code

Tags: linux, bash, shell, svn, jenkins

We are using a script to copy code from trunk to branches and from one branch to another branch in same repo. Using rev no. we are getting files changed and then exporting those files only. I want to implement the script in a way so that it can take multiple rev from user at once through a file and keeps on running until all revs are done. Also, with every rev it should copy the complete commit message of that specified rev and feed it as current message.

```
#!/bin/bash
output=`ps -ef | grep svn | wc -l`

if [ "$output" -gt "3" ] ; then

echo "Svn script already running on another machine"

exit 0;

else

echo "Processing"


read -p "revision - " revision
read -p "message - " message

read -p "username - " username

stty -echo

read -p "password - " password

stty echo

echo "";

echo "Updating working copy"

/usr/bin/svn up /QA/ --username $username --password $password --non-interactive

/usr/bin/svn log --verbose -r  "$revision" http://192.168.62.224/live/repos --username $username --password $password --non-interactive | grep trunk | awk '{print $2}' > /opt/trunk-list.txt

cp /opt/trunk-list.txt  /opt/ren.txt

sed -i  's/trunk/home/g' /opt/ren.txt

cat /opt/trunk-list.txt | while read line

do

found=`echo $line | cut -c 7-`
dest="/QA$found"

/usr/bin/svn export  http://192.168.62.224/live/repos/$line $dest --force --username $username --password $password --non-interactive

/usr/bin/svn add $dest --force

done


cd /QA/

/usr/bin/svn commit -m "$message |Dev:$revision" --username $username --password $password --non-interactive

# For update SVN working copy

cat /opt/ren.txt | while read file
do
svn up $file --username $username --password $password --non-interactive
done

fi
```

Comment: I don't really understand the relationship between this script and what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to modify this script? Which parts do you want to change and which parts do you want to keep? I don't understand your requirement.

Comment: I want to keep all parts of this script. currently we have to run this script individually for every rev no we want to process. i wanted to add a functionality in which i will create a file a.txt put all multiple rev in it and feed the file to script so that script will run all rev in its own one by one. As all rev will have different commit message. it should also copy log message maybe using svnlook and give it as message for svn ci as mentioned in above script. I hope this clears my intention to you.

Comment: @janos can you please help me.

Comment: Currently the script is interactive: it asks the user a revision number, message, username, password. Would you still like to ask those (except revision), and then read the revision numbers from a file?

Comment: yes i want to ask all that from user except revision no. and message. It should take rev. no. recursively from txt file. check logs as its doing now. perform all the task as its doing now plus for every revision it should take message corresponding to that revision and use it as commit message in that loop. Then same process for other revision.